# Magento2 staging getting error in my custom module

Tags: magento-2.1, error, custom-options, frontend-error, staging

I am facing this error in our staging environment  Exception: Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given

here added my code

```
$hash = array();
$hash['0'] = 'test';
$array_out = array();
foreach($data as $i_tem) {
    $hash_key = $i_tem[2];

 if(!array_key_exists($hash_key, $hash)) {
        $hash[$hash_key] = sizeof($array_out);
        array_push($array_out, array(
            'id' => $i_tem[2],
            'title' => $i_tem[4],
            'count' => 0,
        ));
    }
 $array_out[$hash[$hash_key]]['count'] += 1;
}
```

Comment: when do you get this error ?

Comment: when i execute in array than this error facing

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/164311/what-is-causing-installschema-error-warning-array-key-exists-expects-paramete/164344#164344

Comment: Please provide  some code , the error is clear here that array_key_exists() function expect second parameter to be array but its getting null value . We can guide you better after seeing some code that you have implemented.

Comment: I have put my code  please check it

Comment: where is your array_key_exists()  ?

Comment: please check it again my put code

Answer (score 1):

Please try with below code :

```
if (is_array($hash) && array_key_exists($hash_key, $hash))
    {
       //...magic stuff here 
    }
```

**hope its work for you**